# Relay does not toggled to OFF sometimes

Tags: relay, inductance

SRD-05VDC-SL-C relay does not turn to OFF sometimes.
Loads - is light bulbs 220V E27.
Ilyich light bulbs (tungsten filament) - work correctly.
Problem in LED bulbs and fluorescent bulbs.
20% [LED bulbs](http://slarkenergy.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/lampa-svetodiodnaya.jpg) in 30% of the time does not turn OFF.
50% [fluorescent bulbs](https://mmedia.ozone.ru/multimedia/1020242846.jpg) in 50% of the time does not turn OFF.
Relays is sticks/adhere/latching due to inductive loads.
LED indicator (example L1A15) turns off, but bulb does not.
What need to do?

[image]

Comment: What are the chips? My guess: U3A is ULN2003? If so, most likely the flyback diode causes the coil magnetic field to collapse too slowly so the relay contacts try to open too slowly and get welded.

Comment: Sorry. ULN2803. I try about 20 pcs ULN2803